# Google Sheets how to get value on certain row if the column is Today()?

Tags: google-sheets

I have these sheets on Google Sheets

```
Sheet "Alpha"
    A       B      C        D  
1 Date    03/11   03/12   03/13
2 Status  DONE    DONE    In Risk

Sheet "Beta"
    A       B      C        D  
1 Date    03/11   03/12   03/13
2 Status  DONE    DONE    DONE

Sheet "Gamma"
    A       B      C           D  
1 Date    03/11   03/12       03/13
2 Status  DONE    In Risk    BLOCKED
```

I want to make a summary sheet with result on daily based as below:

Let's suppose today is **03/13**

```
Sheet "Summary"
    A       B    
1 Name    Status
2 Alpha   In Risk
3 Beta    DONE
4 Gamma   BLOCKED
```

I want to populate the column A using script or function.
So, the step on my mind would be:

1. Populate column A with script/function
2. On column B using formula for:

   - Finding the Today date on other sheet
   - Get value of the row on the column from today date from other sheer

Is it possible to do? How to do it?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Sheet "Summary"**

**Finding by name in Column A**

Cell B2: `=HLOOKUP(TODAY(),INDIRECT(A2&"!$1:$2"),2,0)`

Cell B3: `=HLOOKUP(TODAY(),INDIRECT(A3&"!$1:$2"),2,0)`

Cell B4: `=HLOOKUP(TODAY(),INDIRECT(A4&"!$1:$2"),2,0)`

---

**Finding by Sheet**

Cell B2: `=HLOOKUP(TODAY(),Alpha!$1:$2,2,0)`

Cell B3: `=HLOOKUP(TODAY(),Beta!$1:$2,2,0)`

Cell B4: `=HLOOKUP(TODAY(),Gamma!$1:$2,2,0)`

---

**Function References**

- [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks! It was never crossed to my mind to use HLOOKUP()...lol, joke on me...